# How to use password from environment variable in linux command?

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to run below command in a script (means I cannot run interactively in a terminal and therefore can enter password when prompted):

> ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@example.com  'echo mypassword |
>   sudo -kS ufw status

'

this will ssh into remote host and run command ufw status on remote host.

The command works fine but I need to be able to reference 'password' from environment variable named

> SSHPASS = mypassword

which stores the password in order not to expose the password in the command. How to do that?

Comment: seriously?? use ssh keys.

Comment: Already said in some answers, but it's more secure to use SSH key-based authentication (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server).

Comment: Telling people to "use SSH keys" with embedded devices that don't support such workflows, is the complete opposite of helpful. It's VERY common for IOT and embedded devices to ONLY support password authentication.

Comment: On a Synology NAS, ssh keys are not an option for any normal user (I know, very annoying but I'm facing this issue at the moment), so indeed, commenting "use ssh keys" is unhelpful.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the variable containig the password to `ssh` via the `sshpass` command:

```
sshpass -p "$SSHPASS" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@example.com
```

That said, that's not much more secure than having the password in the script!

A better solution when you need to access servers via `ssh` in scripts would be moving to *key based authentication*.

Comment: even if key based auth, would still require being prompted for password when running command as sudo on remote host.

Comment: @user61766 true, but sudo can be configured not to require a password for certain commands for certain users. You can configure on the remote server(s) a dedicated user for these automation tasks with ssh keys and and ad-hoc `sudo` configuration.

Comment: Maybe sth like `<< $pass << tty`?

Comment: With sshpass you can also set `$SSHPASS` environment variable and use `-e` flag.

Answer (score 3):

There is an answer to this specific question of using `ssh` with a password from an environment variable. Although an ssh key is likely a better approach in most situations, there are some scenarios in which this might be helpful.

Mr Shunz was on the right track with `sshpass` and was right to suggest avoiding `sshpass -p "$SSHPASS"` as it would print out the password.

Instead, we can use `sshpass -e`, which invokes `ssh` with a password directly from the environment variable `SSHPASS` without printing it out.

1. `export SSHPASS` in to your environment (manually, through `.bashrc`, or some other config)
2. Prefix your `ssh` commands with `sshpass -e`, e.g. `sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@example.com <command>`

Read the [sshpass man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to accomplish this would be to set up an SSH key for the root user on the remote system which is restricted to invoke "ufw status".

Having said that, if I understand what you're trying to do, you just need to supply a password to the `sudo` program. For that, either of these should work:

```
echo "$PASSWORD" | ssh -o ... user@example.com 'sudo -kS ufw status'

ssh -o ... user@example.com "echo $PASSWORD | sudo -kS ufw status"
```

The main difference between these is the first version runs `echo` on the local system, while the second version runs `echo` on the remote system. Running a command with a password as one of its command-line arguments has the potential to make the password visible to other users. By running running `echo` on one host or the other, you're making the password visible to a different group of users.